# Android Lint: mark variables as final whenever applicable in Java

Tags: java, android, final, lint

Is there any Lint check to enforce declaring every variable (local or class), parameter final if they really are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there's no check for that. Checkstyle or PMD can do this for you. Note that both won't work with Kotlin though.

- [Checkstyle FinalLocalVariableCheck](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/FinalLocalVariableCheck.html)
- [Checkstyle LocalFinalVariableNameCheck](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/naming/LocalFinalVariableNameCheck.html)
- [more in config_misc](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html)
- [PMD MethodArgumentCouldBeFinal](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.1.0/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#methodargumentcouldbefinal)
- [PMD LocalVariableCouldBeFinal](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.1.0/pmd_rules_java_codestyle.html#localvariablecouldbefinal)

You could also write your own lint check for that. I've written a blog post about it that goes into detail - https://medium.com/@vanniktech/writing-your-first-lint-check-39ad0e90b9e6

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the comprehensive answer, it provides me all the information, especially the blog link.